# Minimize $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_i \over {a_{i-1}+a_i}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B>0, n\in \mathbb{N}$. I want to find the maximal possible value of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_i \over {a_{i-1}+a_i}}$ where $a_0, \dots, a_n >0$ and $a_0=A,a_n=B$.

My approach is to notice that maximizing the given product is equivalent to minimizing its reciprocal $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}{{a_{i-1}+a_i} \over a_i}= {a_0+a_1 \over a_1}{a_1+a_2 \over a_2}\dots{a_{n-1}+a_n \over a_n}=\left( {a_0 \over a_1}+1 \right)\left( {a_1 \over a_2}+1 \right)\dots \left( {a_{n-1} \over a_n}+1 \right)$$
Since ${a_{i-1} \over a_i}+1>1$, the reciprocal is minimized for $n=1$
$$ {a_0 \over a_1}+1 = {A \over B}+1 = {A+B \over B}$$
and the original product is ${B \over A+B}$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing partial derivatives with respect to $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{n-1}$ of $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{i-1}+a_i}{a_i}$ and equating it to $0$ you get that $a_i=\sqrt{a_{i-1}a_{i+1}}$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots, (n-1)$
solving for few $n$ for example $n=2,3,4$

for $n=2$ you get $a_1=\sqrt{AB}$

for $n=3$ you get $a_1=\sqrt[3]{A^2B},a_2=\sqrt[3]{AB^2}$

for $n=4$ you get $a_1=\sqrt[4]{A^3B},a_2=\sqrt{AB},a_3=\sqrt[4]{AB^3}$

From this you can guess that the formula is ( I've used $/$ for better readability)  $$a_i=A^{(n-i)/n}B^{i/n}$$
This satisfies the formula $a_i=\sqrt{a_{i-1}a_{i+1}}$ we get that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{i-1}+a_i}{a_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n(\frac{a_{i-1}}{a_i}+1)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\frac{A^{(n-i+1)/n}B^{(i-1)/n}}{A^{(n-i)/n}B^{i/n}}+1)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\frac{A^{1/n}}{B^{1/n}}+1)=\left(1+\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{1/n}\right)^n$$
There still needs some justification that this really is a minimum,I'll leave it to you(shouldn't be that hard but currently I'm out of idea).